# ldconfig register .so lib

Tags: linux, unix, gcc, go

I am running `go build` and encounter following issue:

```
/tmp/___go_build_myproject_: error while loading shared libraries: libSomeLib_x64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have `libSomeLib_x64.so` compiled in another directory.
From [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44990/152046) I know that I should use ldconfig to link lib.

I tried both add lib path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but nothing helped. How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: I this through cgo? Can you provide more details including your cgo code above the `import "C"` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here: https://codeyarns.com/2017/11/02/how-shared-library-locations-are-found-at-runtime/

I added my `*.so` libs into `/lib/` directory.